# Error Propogation Through Matrix Equation

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, covariance, error-propagation

I have an iterative matrix equation that takes the form:
$$\vec{f}^{(s+1)} = \matrix{M}^{(s)}.\vec{d}$$
Where $\matrix{M}^{(s)}$ is a function of $\vec{f}^{(s)}$ and a response matrix $\matrix{R}$, and $\vec{d}$ is my raw data vector. A bit of research on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Linear_combinations) suggests that if the only thing that had uncertainties was  $\vec{d}$ then I could simply calculate the covariance matrix for $\vec{f}^{(s+1)}$ using the following equation.
$$\matrix{V}_{f^{(s+1)}} = \matrix{M}^{(s)}.\matrix{V}_d.{\matrix{M}^{(s)}}^T$$

Where $\matrix{V}_d$ is the covariance matrix of $\vec{d}$.

However, I also have uncertainties in the response matrix, $\matrix{R}$, that is used to calculate $\matrix{M}^{(s)}$. Thus my question:

**How do I propagate my uncertainties through a linear formula where both the matrix and vector have uncertainties?**
*Are there methods other than brute force Taylor expansion to do this?*

*Edit:* I have seen a [method](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3220/2008su/slides/linearsystemerror.pdf) to propagate the errors, however it relies on the invertability of $\matrix{M}^{(s)}$ and merely gives magnitudes of errors across the whole matrix. Sadly, my matrix is not square, ($\matrix{M}^{(s)}$ is (1500x3200)), and I need the actual covariance matrix, not a general percentage error applying to the whole matrix.

Comment: This could be interesting: [Variance of the product of a random matrix and a random vector](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28229/variance-of-the-product-of-a-random-matrix-and-a-random-vector)

Comment: That is interesting, Unfortunately, my parameters are definitely not i.i.d. there will be off diagonal elements in the covariance matrix, without a doubt. But I will definitely have to read a bit through the question and answer, along with matrix cookbook that was linked to figure out what was going on. Maybe that can give me a good road to go down.

Comment: I think the whole thing is going to be extremely unpleasant because $M^{(s)}$ and $\vec d$ will be correlated in a complicated way. Could you simulate the experiment and get the covariance matrix that way?

Comment: I agree with that assessment. As to the simulation, not really. $\matrix{R}$ is the response matrix of a detector to gamma radiation incident on it each cell is the probability that you observe a given energy depositted (column) for a given energy incident (row). That took about ~4500 cpu hours to simulate. That simulation is then used to iteratively determine what was the radiation incident on the detector given the observed spectrum $\vec{d}$. I then apply this to thousands of spectra. I am not sure *how* to simulate that, let alone willing to burn ~4500 cpu hours per spectrum.

Comment: What I meant was drawing vectors ${\vec d}{}' = \vec d + \vec n$, where $\vec n$ is normally distributed with zero mean and the covariance you have for $\vec d$, and looking at the distribution of the output of your iterative scheme for many such draws. That will give you an approximate covariance matrix and requires you to only run the iterations, which I assumed to be fast.

Comment: Ah, that could work, could something similar be done with the matrix part $\matrix{M}^{(s)}$? I know how to handle the variance of the data on its own, (second equation of my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you can find the covariance for the elements of the matrices $M^{(s)}$ from $R$, I think a little progress can be made. We have
$$
f_i = \sum_j M_{ij} d_j
$$
with expectation value
$$
\mathrm{E}[f_i]
= \sum_j \mathrm{E}[M_{ij} d_j]
= \sum_j \mathrm{E}[M_{ij}] \mathrm{E}[d_j]
+ \sum_j \mathrm{Cov}[M_{ij}, d_j]
$$
and covariance matrix
$$
\mathrm{Cov}[f_i, f_j]
= \sum_{k,l} \mathrm{Cov}[M_{ik} d_k, M_{jl} d_l] \;.
$$
I do not know of a more explicit expression for the covariance of the products of random variables than that given in [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2286081), which does not seem to make life much easier here. However, it mentions an approximation for the covariance,
$$
\begin{multline}
\mathrm{Cov}[f_i, f_j]
\approx \sum_{k,l} \big\{
 \mathrm{E}[M_{ik}] \, \mathrm{E}[M_{jl}] \, \mathrm{Cov}[d_k, d_l]
 + \mathrm{E}[M_{ik}] \, \mathrm{E}[d_l] \, \mathrm{Cov}[d_k, M_{jl}]\\
 + \mathrm{E}[d_k] \, \mathrm{E}[M_{jl}] \, \mathrm{Cov}[M_{ik}, d_l]
 + \mathrm{E}[d_k] \, \mathrm{E}[d_l] \, \mathrm{Cov}[M_{ik}, M_{jl}]
\big\} \;.
\end{multline}
$$
Due to the iterative nature, there is going to be correlation between $M^{(s)}$ and $\vec d$, which depends on the function that computes the matrix. Now, if you can reasonably ignore that covariance, then you are left with
$$
\mathrm{Cov}[f_i, f_j]
\approx \sum_{k,l} \big\{
 \mathrm{E}[M_{ik}] \, \mathrm{E}[M_{jl}] \, \mathrm{Cov}[d_k, d_l]
 + \mathrm{E}[d_k] \, \mathrm{E}[d_l] \, \mathrm{Cov}[M_{ik}, M_{jl}]
\big\} \;,
$$
which looks almost manageable.